# how to get name of USB module in android

Tags: android, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to get the name USB module as i want to block loading of USB module in android
for the I am using lsmod to get list of loadable module and it is showing the following output

```
# lsmod
lsmod
bcm4329 204281 0 - Live 0xbf09e000
vpnclient 62940 1 - Live 0xbf000000
```

but how Can i Know which is USB Module from the above 2

Please help!!!

Comment: bcm4329 - is Broadcom module (wifi/bt, not usb); vpnclient - could be anything but do not expect that to be usb module from the name.

Comment: lsusb which list the Usb commedted device.

Comment: What do you mean by "USB module"? Is your system controlling other USB devices? (USB host controller) or is your system being controlled by another device? What behavior are you trying to prevent?

Comment: for security issue. so that user can't transfer data through USB I want to block USB Port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need recompile the kernel and disable all USB options. I'm fairly certain that USB support is compiled in and not set as a module. Note that "adb" uses USB, so by disabling USB you may have other problems. I.e. not able to obtain a remote shell to your phone.

Comment: thanks for the reply , As I also need shell for my other tasks,So have to find other way.                                                     Can we handle USB interrupts??

Comment: There is an app called "adb wifi". That allows you to run adb over the network. This would allow you to completely disable USB.